# ionic login button not working in android

Tags: button, authentication, ionic-framework

Button is working when run on browser using **ionic serve** and **ionic serve --lab**  command. I am able to login in web browser and redirected to dashboard. 
When I generate .apk file and run on android device....login button is not working.

Not redirected to dashboard by click on login button with username and password.

I have tried this reference: [Ionic android button not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36873281/ionic-android-button-not-working)

but still not get success...please give me any solution .

**Login Template**

```
      <li class="item-content">
                  <div class="item-inner">
                    <div class="item-input">
                       <label class="item item-input">
                      <input class="style login3" type="email" name="email" placeholder="E-mail" ng-model="user.email">
                      </label>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </li>
                <li class="item-content">
                  <div class="item-inner">
                    <div class="item-input">
                       <label class="item item-input">
                      <input class="style login3" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" ng-model="user.pwdForLogin">
</label>                   
                      </div>
                      </div>
                      </li>

                       </div>
                         <button ng-click="signIn(user)" >
                      Sign In
                   </button>
```

**App.js**

```
// State to represent Login View
    .state('login', {
        url: "/login",
        templateUrl: "templates/login.html",
        controller: 'LoginCtrl',
        resolve: {
            // controller will not be loaded until $waitForAuth resolves
            // Auth refers to our $firebaseAuth wrapper in the example above
            "currentAuth": ["Auth",
                function (Auth) {
                    // $waitForAuth returns a promise so the resolve waits for it to complete
                    return Auth.$waitForAuth();
        }]
        }
    })
```

Please help me....

Answer (score 0):

Here I will show you a working example and you can use it for your code.

**MY Custom CSS**

```
    .bgLogin{
  width: 100%;
  background-image: url("http://static.vecteezy.com/system/resources/previews/000/084/251/original/christmas-bokeh-vector-background.jpg");
  background-size: 100% 100% !important;
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
.login-content
{
  margin-top:8%;
  padding:0px 10px 0px 10px;
}
.login-content .login-form
{
  margin-top:40%;
}
```

**View/HTML**

```
    <ion-view class="bgLogin" name="login-view">
  <ion-nav-bar>
    <ion-nav-back-button></ion-nav-back-button>
  </ion-nav-bar>
  <ion-content class="login-content">
    <div class="login-form">
      <label class="item item-input">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Username" ng-model="data.username">
      </label>
      <label class="item item-input">
        <input type="password" placeholder="Password" ng-model="data.password">
      </label>
    </div>
    <button class="button button-block login-button" ng-click="login()">Login</button>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

**App.js**
Assuming your adding references to controller and service

```
var appStarter = angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'starter.controllers', 'starter.services']);
```

*define state*

```
.state('login', {
  url: '/login',
  templateUrl: 'templates/login.html',
  controller: 'LoginCtrl'
})
```

**controller for login**

```
    appControllers.controller('LoginCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope, LoginService, $ionicPopup, $state, $ionicHistory) {
    $scope.data = {};

    $scope.login = function() {
      LoginService.loginUser($scope.data.username, $scope.data.password).success(function(data) {
        $rootScope.userName = $scope.data.username.toUpperCase();
        $ionicHistory.nextViewOptions({
          disableBack: true
        });
        $state.go('app.welcome');
      }).error(function(data) {
        var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
          title: 'Login failed!',
          template: 'Please check your credentials!',
            buttons: [
                {
                    text: 'Ok',
                    type: 'orange-btn'
                }
            ]
        });
      });
    }
  });
```

**Service for login**

```
    .service('LoginService', function($q) {
    return {
      loginUser: function(name, pw) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        var promise = deferred.promise;

        if (name.toLowerCase() == 'ens' && pw == 'ens' || name.toLowerCase() == 'adam' && pw == 'adam'|| name.toLowerCase() == 'illum' && pw == 'illum'|| name.toLowerCase() == 'test' && pw == 'test') {
          deferred.resolve('Welcome ' + name + '!');
        } else {
          deferred.reject('Wrong credentials.');
        }
        promise.success = function(fn) {
          promise.then(fn);
          return promise;
        }
        promise.error = function(fn) {
          promise.then(null, fn);
          return promise;
        }
        return promise;
      }
    }
  });
```